# Using Voicemeeter to stream game audio through Skype

Tags: windows, audio, skype, audio-streaming

I'm looking to share a game with friends over Skype. Skype provides the voice chat and screen share functionalities natively, but has no way to capture game sound. After some digging, I found [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/841104/530238), which suggested Voicemeeter. Voicemeeter actually works great for this purpose, with two real exceptions.

First, if I want to use it, I have to go into my Windows sound settings to make Voicemeeter my default recording and playback devices, then do the same in Skype. When I'm done, I have to close the program and set everything back. This is a minor hassle, and the old question suggests that "you can close it to return to normal without having to restart if you configure it correctly." I can't find whatever configuration option that is, so I'm hoping someone more familiar with the program can give me some guidance there.

Second, sometimes other members of the skype call get echoes of their voices. It's not all the time, which suggests there's some filtering going on on Voicemeeter's part, but I can't seem to find how to configure that, either.

Answer (score 1):

To your second question:

For your use case you will need Voicemeeter Banana instead of vanilla Voicemeeter. Banana has three hardware inputs, two virtual inputs, three hardware outputs, and two virtual outputs. This is important because you need at least two virtual inputs and separate hardware and virtual outputs.

You should have your game audio and your default system audio coming in one of your virtual inputs. You should set your Skype and default communications audio to come in the other virtual input. You'll also have a hardware input for your microphone. You'll have a hardware output for your headphones/speakers, and a virtual output for Skype's microphone. Send your system audio to both outputs, send communications audio only to your headphones, and send your microphone only to your virtual output.

This way you will never cross skype output with skype input.

Comment: (1) If we send default system audio to a virtual input, doesn't that also send the game audio? But do we even want that? Do we want all system sounds mixed with game audio? (2) Skype audio output can be set in the Skype app, but where is "default communications audio" set and is this even needed?